# Как записать SQL INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql

На сервер приходят данные:

```
Session_Id, Resived_Value1, Resived_Value2, Resived_Value3
```

Есть такие таблицы:

- Table1.User_Id='3' Tabel1.Session_Id='Some_Id'
- Tabel2.Drawi_Id='11'

Хочу проверить если `SessionId` верный, тогда добавить все это в одну таблицу `Table3` столбцы:

```
User_id Draw_Id Value1 Value2 Value3
```

Не хватает фантазии, как это можно сделать

Вот моя попытка

```
INSERT INTO `table3` t3
  (`t3`.`user_id`, `t3`.`draw_id`, `t3`.`value1`, `t3`.`value2`, `t3`.`value3`)
VALUES ('
  (SELECT `user_id` FROM `table1` WHERE `session_id`="Session_id ";),
  (SELECT `draws_id` FROM `table2` ORDER BY `draws_id` DESC LIMIT 1;),
  value1, value2, value3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table3 (user_id, draw_id, value1, value2, value3)
SELECT t1.user_id, (SELECT MAX(draws_id) FROM table2), @value1, @value2, @value3
FROM table1 t1
WHERE table1.session_id='Session_id'
```